# how to show an improper integral is well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

Let $g$ be continuous on [0,1] and assume that $f$ is continuous on (0,1]. Assume further that for any $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\epsilon}^{1} f(s)\, ds=\int_{h(\epsilon)}^{1} g(u)\,du
\end{align*}
where $h(\epsilon)\in (0,1)$ and $h(\epsilon)\to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

I want to show that the improper integral 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}f(s)\,ds
\end{align*}
is well defined.

My question is that how to show an improper integral is well defined? Do I need to use Cauthy's criterion to that this integral is bounded by some other well defined integral?

Comment: The limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ of the integral on the right-hand side is $\int_0^1 g(u)\,du$, which exists since $g$ is continuous in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The improper integral is well defined if $\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_e^1 f(s) \,ds$ exists.

Since $g$ is continuous and integrable on $[0,1]$ you can take your pick of ways to prove this.

Using the Cauchy criterion we have

$$\left|\int_\alpha^\beta f(s) \, ds   \right| = \left|\int_{h(\alpha)}^{h(\beta)} g(s) \, ds   \right| \leqslant \sup_{[0,1]}|g|\,|h(\beta) - h(\alpha)| \longrightarrow _{\alpha,\beta \to 0} 0$$